# StringIndexOutOfBounds exception when calling an api POST request with a request body

Tags: android, retrofit2

I can see that many of my users have started experiencing a crash when making a certain api call in my app.
It seems like an internal library crash, though.

I can see two stacktraces recurring :

```
Caused by java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String 
index out of range: 6422625
       at java.lang.String.codePointAt(String.java:602)
       at java.util.WeakHashMap.transfer(WeakHashMap.java:499)
       at java.util.WeakHashMap.resize(WeakHashMap.java:475)
       at java.util.WeakHashMap.put(WeakHashMap.java:448)
       at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.put(Collections.java:2318)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:573)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:741)
       at libcore.reflect.AnnotationFactory.createAnnotation(AnnotationFactory.java:95)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotationsNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotations(Method.java:594)
       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.(ServiceMethod.java:158)
       at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
       at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
       at $Proxy2.a(Unknown Source)
  ... 

Caused by java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 16
   at java.lang.String.codePointAt(String.java:602)
   at java.util.WeakHashMap.transfer(WeakHashMap.java:499)
   at java.util.WeakHashMap.resize(WeakHashMap.java:475)
   at java.util.WeakHashMap.put(WeakHashMap.java:448)
   at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.put(Collections.java:2318)
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:573)
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:741)
   at libcore.reflect.AnnotationFactory.createAnnotation(AnnotationFactory.java:95)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotationsNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotations(Method.java:594)
   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.(ServiceMethod.java:158)
   at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
   at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
   at $Proxy2.a(Unknown Source)
```

Most of our users are Samsung galaxy users, and those affected mostly use Android 7. 
Any idea what this might be caused by?

The retrofit method is a post method with a request body, with custom headers, and we use interceptors as well.

Another issue put into the same crash type in crashlytics is a follows :

```
Caused by java.lang.ArrayStoreException: android.os.Parcel cannot be stored in an array of type java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry[]
   at java.util.WeakHashMap.transfer(WeakHashMap.java:507)
   at java.util.WeakHashMap.resize(WeakHashMap.java:475)
   at java.util.WeakHashMap.put(WeakHashMap.java:448)
   at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.put(Collections.java:2318)
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:573)
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:741)
   at libcore.reflect.AnnotationFactory.createAnnotation(AnnotationFactory.java:95)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotationsNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotations(Method.java:594)
   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.(ServiceMethod.java:158)
   at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
   at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
   at $Proxy2.a(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It might help if you post the Retrofit method in question, and a sample of a place in your code where you use it.

Comment: Well it's all over the place as we use Dagger. But it doesn't happen on our test devices so it's not a general issue of the implementation. I rather think it's a retrofit or jdk bug. No idea what could help?